# Am I Calling Javascript/ CSS pages/ files wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```
<script src="scripts/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/lib/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<link href="./styles/w3ds.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./styles/w3ds-data-tables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="https://1.www.s81c.com/common/v18/css/www.css" rel="stylesheet">


<link href="./styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="scripts/app/run.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/config.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/ctrl-all-ee.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/ctrl-2.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/awtrun.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/app/Params.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/directives.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/services.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app/filters.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Working in eclipse to build an application, I have multiple .js files and multiple .css files but for some the angularjs is not working, its not reading the other .html or .js files. Any ideas why this may be happening. Thanks for the help.

```
<!-- Small Screen Hamburger -->
<div class="ds-col-xs-3 ds-col-sm-2 ds-hide-md ds-float-right">
    <a class="ds-button ds-flat" ng-click="overlayShow('#overlay-mini-menu')">
        <span class="ds-icon-menu ds-icon-size-default"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<!-- Small Screen Hamburger Overlay -->
<div class="ds-overlay-container">
    <div class="ds-overlay-focus" id="overlay-mini-menu" ng-click="overlayHide()">
        <div class="ds-overlay-box gsi-overlay-main" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
            <div class="gsi-overlay-heading ds-padding-bottom-2">
                <button class="ds-col-auto ds-button ds-flat" ng-click="overlayHide()">
                    <span id="overlay-mini-menu-open"></span><span class="ds-icon-x"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="gsi-content">
                <div class="ds-margin-top-1_5">
                    <a href="./#/allee" class="ds-button ds-flat" ng-click="overlayHide()">Deployment Overview</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EX.   href="./#/allee">

Deployment Overview

Above is how i'm attempting to call the other .html files. I'm trying to avoid one long drawn out .html file and instead have multiple to easily decipher/manage/update the code. But my ./#/allee (.html) is not reflecting when I load the page.

Comment: What's your application directory look like? from the route of your application to scripts folder?

Comment: Since you don't have a <head> tag and your question ends with </body> my guess is that you are not putting the links you have posted in the <head> section, where it should be

Comment: What is serving your files? If it's a server, can you paste the code?

Comment: Hello, could you tell me what ds-* library is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a folder lets say: assets. Load all the files into this folder but keep the folder structure. From the html file get files as:

assets/scripts/lib/angular.min.js

This assumes you load files relatively so folder assets must be in the same directory as you html page.

Repeat the same for all of the remaining files to include.